# django upgrade from 1.9 to 1.10 __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'current_app'

Tags: python, django

ive just upgraded Django from 1.9 to 1.10. i run 1.10 in my test environment and ironed out any upgrade issues to make sure it all worked.

however when ive gone to do it on my live site and gone to load the home page i get the errors below

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://it.local.com/

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('home.apps.HomeConfig',
 'oncall.apps.OncallConfig',
 'tools.apps.ToolsConfig',
 'sites.apps.SitesConfig',
 'maintenance.apps.MaintenanceConfig',
 'service.apps.ServiceConfig',
 'management.apps.ManagementConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'bootstrap_pagination',
 'easy_thumbnails')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/var/www/infternal/home/views.py" in index
  13.     return render(request, 'home/index.html', {"user": user})

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  49.         context_instance = RequestContext(request, current_app=current_app)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'current_app'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't installed Django 1.10 properly. The line from the traceback `context_instance = RequestContext(request, current_app=current_app)` does not exist in Django 1.10. I would try uninstalling and reinstalling Django, and then restarting the server.

Comment: i did pip uninstall django and pip install django and it now seems to have worked